# Двумерный массив элементов

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, массивы

Здравствуйте. У меня не получается создать двумерный массив лейблов. Пытаюсь создать вот так:

```
Label[,] element = new Label[MAX, MAX];
```

На меня ругаются вот так:

> Необработанное исключение типа
> "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException"
> в PresentationFramework.dll

upd: путем добавления

```
element[i,j] = new Label();
```

Всё стало работать корректно. Но теперь появилась следующая проблема, с таким же сообщением об ошибке.
Мой код теперь имеет такой вид:

```
private Label[,] element = new Label[MAX, MAX];
    private void CreateLabel(int height, int width) {

        int Hloc = 0;
        int Wloc = 12;

        for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < MAX; j++) {

                element[i,j] = new Label();

                element[i, j].Height = 40;
                element[i, j].Width = 40;
                element[i, j].HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                element[i, j].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                element[i, j].Margin = new Thickness(Wloc, Hloc, 0, 0);

                grid.Children.Add(element[i,j]);

                Wloc += 45;
            }
            Hloc += 45;
            Wloc = 12;
        }
    }

    private void CreateNumbers()
    {
        if (element[x, y].Content.ToString() != ""){

             element[x, y].Content = GetNum().ToString();
        }
    }
```

И проблема заключается вот в этом кусочке:

```
        if (element[x, y].Content.ToString() != ""){

             element[x, y].Content = GetNum().ToString();
        }
```

Почему я не могу после добавления элемента в грид, обратиться к нему как к элементу массива?

Comment: Приведите код целиком. По данному фрагменту нельзя определить, в чём состоит проблема.

Comment: @AlexeyM, это и был весь код. Решил проблему путем добавления данной строки:
> element[i,j] = new Label();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Из комментариев:** 
Решил проблему путем добавления данной строки: > element[i,j] = new Label()